# Regex to capture option and string following it from a menu

Tags: python, regex

I would like to capture every option and the text following it using the following regex. Strangely, the regex only captures numbered options with one digit. Any help is appreciated.

```
>>> s = '[a] Option a\n[1] Option 2\n[12] option 12'
>>> re.findall('\[([a-z]|[\d\+])\]\s+(.*)?\\r?\\n?', s,re.M)
[('a', 'Option a'), ('1', 'Option 2')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `[\d\+]` to `\d+`, `[\d\+]` will match either single digit or `+` sign

```
>>> s = '[a] Option a\n[1] Option 2\n[12] option 12'
>>> re.findall('\[([a-z\d]+)\]\s+(.*)?\\r?\\n?', s)
[('a', 'Option a'), ('1', 'Option 2'), ('12', 'option 12')]
```

Comment: I like your solution best.

Comment: Just FYI: `re.M` is totally redundant.

Comment: @stribizhev : thanks, /i'm not familiar with python.... anyway updated the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the backslash before the + sign, to not escape it by accident.

After some tinkering I ended up with

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '[a] Option a\n[1] Option 2\n[12] option 12'
>>> re.findall('\[(\w+)\]\s+(.*)', s)
[('a', 'Option a'), ('1', 'Option 2'), ('12', 'option 12')]
```

Comment: Ah.. The backslash before + was unintended. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Happens to me often enough too.

Comment: Actually, you also need to remove the square brackets around that `\d+`.

Answer (score 1):

These seem overly complex. This captures the groups you are looking for.

```
re.findall('\[(\w+)\]\s(\w*\s\w+)', s,re.M)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL8rQ9/2#python)